# Resetting nested radio button selection with cancel button

Tags: javascript

I have a page where I'm using radio buttons to determine some user options.
Option 1 will have two options within it and Option 2 is stand alone.

The HTML is as follows:

```
<div>
  <input type="radio" name="level0" value="D" id="D" checked="checked" />
  <label for="D">D</label>
  <div class="sub1">
    <div>
      <input type="radio" name="level1" value="D0" id="D0" />
      <label for="D0">D0</label>
    </div>
    <div>
      <input type="radio" name="level1" value="D1" id="D1" checked="checked" />
      <label for="D1">D1</label>
    </div>
  </div>
  <input type="radio" name="level0" value="E" id="E" />
  <label for="E">E</label>
  <br>
  <br>
  <button id="cancel-btn" type="button">Cancel</button>
</div>
```

The problem revolves around the cancel button functionality.
Assuming that the radios with the 'checked' attributes are the default settings, if I start to update these but then decide to not go through with the update and hit the cancel button, I want it to revert to the default settings.

The JavaScript extract that handles this is

```
$('#E').click(function (event) {
    $("#D0").attr('checked', false);
    $('#D1').attr('checked', false);
});
$('#D0').click(function (event) {
    $('#E').attr('checked', false);
    $('#D').attr('checked', true);
});
$('#D1').click(function (event) {
    $('#E').attr('checked', false);
    $('#D').attr('checked', true);
});
$('#cancel-btn').click(function (event) {
    $('input[type=radio]').prop('checked', function () {
        return this.getAttribute('checked') == 'checked';
    });
});
```

The problem is that the outer radio buttons are being reset but the inner (D0 and D1) are not.

Thoughts?

Comment: Reason you do not use `type="reset"` for the button?

Comment: For better understanding, Please provide a **working demo** (*code snippet,jsfiddle ...*)

Comment: No reason.  Just threw a button in for example purposes but its not making any difference when i change it to reset using that http://jsfiddle.net/ tool.

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/kevindoyleie/3okaz76b

Comment: The checked attribute is getting removed when clicking on the E radio button. Maybe add a default attribute to your default radio buttons and check for that? `<input type="radio" name="level1" value="D1" id="D1" checked="checked" default />`

Comment: All inputs need to be inside a `<form>` for `type="reset"` to work

Comment: Note: They are in a form. I just didn't add that to the example. Apologies.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use this in your cancel button code

```
$('input[type=radio]').attr('checked', false);
$('input[type=radio][default]').attr('checked', true);
```

This is probably what @billy meant, when he said you should add an arbitrary (in this case "default") attribute